# Options Arbitrage

Tags: options, option-pricing, arbitrage

I have a basic question regarding the BSM formula, would be thankful for any assistance.

As far as I understand $N(d2)$ and $N(-d2)$ stand for the probability of a Call and Put respectively being exercised.

If so, isn't it the case that two adjacent same type options with the same expiry must have a difference in premiums of at least the farther strike's exercisable probability times the Multiplier of the contract?

For example:

Option Type - Put

Strike $X - N(-d2) \geq 0.4$

Strike $Y - N(-d2) \geq 0.3$

Option Multiplier - 100

In general, isn;t it the case that:

X Premium $\geq Y Premium + Y \cdot N(-d2) *$ Multiplier

Comment: Where do the numbers 0.4 and 0.3 in the example come from? What do you men by "adjacent options"?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The numbers I used are only an example. "adjacent" meaning: two near strikes (on the same chain). For example: Spot - 1000, Put(960) with a calculated N(d2) of 0.4 and Put(950) with a calculated N(d2) of 0.3. I'm asking if the difference in premiums between them should be at least 0.3, (Put(950) Nd2) times the multiplier?